# Relations among the Action class, JSP page and HTTP request?

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest, struts

With struts, I can request an url like `http://example.com/list.do?xxx=xx` which handled by an Action class and then flow to a JSP file.
And I can also request a JSP page like `http://example.com/list.jsp` directly.
Then what's the relations among these three concept? What dynamic things could I do with a direct JSP page request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent using direct jsp redirection as much as possible. That is the whole concept